# How to explicitly add role to a user in discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm relatively new to programming and am trying to code a bot for a server I'm in. I'd ideally like to assign a user to a specific role based on them sending a message containing 'gm' or 'good morning'. Right now, the bot can read the message and send a reply. But I'm a bit lost trying to figure out how to actually add the role to a user once the 'gm' message is read.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


async def addRole(user : discord.Member, role : discord.Role = BagChaser):

    if role in user.roles:
        return
    else: await user.add_roles(role)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    msg = message.content.lower()

    words_list = ['gm', 'good morning']

    if any(word in msg for word in words_list):
        # await addRole(message.author, BagChaser)
        await message.channel.send(f'Lets get this bag, {message.author}')
        await message.author.add_roles(BagChaser)`
```

the commented line and the last line were some ideas of how to add the role 'BagChaser' to the author of the message. I tried setting the role parameter in the addRole function to BagChaser since that will never change, but this seems incorrect. The role is already made in my server, but I'm not sure how I can make the bot aware of that role in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried explicitly calling out my role but i can't get it recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You need a role object, and to do that, you need a guild object, which you can get with `message.author.guild`.

From this, you can get the Role object:

```py
role = await message.author.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
```

Note that you need to get the role ID yourself. The easiest method to do so is to go into Discord and enable Developer settings, then right click the role on someone's profile and click "Copy ID". Once you have this role object, you can just apply it with `message.author.add_roles(role)`.

Complete code:

```py
role_id = ...

author = message.author;
role = await author.guild.get_role(role_id)
await author.add_roles(role)
```

Make sure your bot has the Manage Roles permission